# How to customize the mouseover-effect of Tiles (Promoted Links)

Tags: 2013, promoted-links, style, view-styles, tiles

I wanted to change the standard-mouseover-effect of SharePoint Tiles (the simply "scroll up" of the "infobox") into sth. more "eye-catchy". I guess it's a job for JavaScript, but I have no idea how to. As an example what kind of effect it could be I've added a link to this post: 
http://www.shortpoint.com/shortpoints/tiles/

I especially like the "Style Sara" and the "Style Flip" of this Website. But this is only an example of what I'm thinking about and doesn't have to be exactly the same. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this could help: http://spapptex.com/